# Detect Change in Select in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, ng-bootstrap, angular11

I have some difficulties logging the year when you select the year.
I managed to hide the month and dates already though.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-year-datepicker-ng-bootstrap-mdpe1p?file=app%2Fdatepicker-basic.ts,app%2Fdatepicker-basic.html)

Simple datepicker

```
<ngb-datepicker
  [(ngModel)]="model"
  (dateSelect)="onDateChange($event)"
></ngb-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my answer will help you. Use `(navigate)="navigateEvent($event)"` instead.

```
navigateEvent(event) {
    console.log(event.next.year);
  }
```